# Billing API 3.0. Price change user notification

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, in-app-billing

I'm currently implementing in-app purchases on Android using Google Play Billing Library 3.0.

There is a section in documentation about [Changing subscription prices](https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/subs#price-change)

Documentation says, that after price increase Google Play begins notifying users of the price change starting seven days after confirmation.

Also, there is a statement "You should notify your existing subscribers whenever you make a price change, especially if the price is increasing.".

It is not clear for me, if it is **obligatory** to show a price change confirmation dialog in-app, or it's just a way to encourage a user to agree to a price change.
Can we rely solely on the Google Play notification? If a user clicks on such notification, can he agree on a price change inside Google Play?

Answer (score 0):

As stated by the documentation, Google is making strong suggestion to app publisher, to communicate with your user/customer about the price change.
App publisher is in the best position to explain why the price is changing.

*To maximize opt-in rates and encourage your users to take action, your app should display messaging to your users about the upcoming price change.*
[See price change section](https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/subscriptions#price-change)